# Play! Framework + Java

Tags: java, playframework

when I try to create a new play app and then launch my play application (without modifying any code) locally I get the following error:

http://cl.ly/image/1x311s1w3S2w

which says I have a continuation error. However I cannot fix it as I have other older play projects which I can still launch and they still work perfectly. My java version in eclipse 1.7 and my play version is 1.2.5.

I realise now that my JVM is 1.8, will this make a difference? Although then why do they older apps still work, when they are also written using 1.7.

Any help at all would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think  the JVM version would be the issue. The issue is with the loading of your class `ContinuationEnhancer`. Try replacing the jar of that class.